# Python NameError at testfunctions

Tags: python, nameerror

I met this problem several times, and don't know how to deal with it. Many of my testfunctions (for example `test_add`) returns a `NameError`, although the tested function is there. For example:

```
def test_add():
   '''Testfunction for add'''
   assert add(1)==[1]
   assert add(2)==[1, 2]
   assert add(3)==[1, 2, 3]
def add(n):
   pass
```

What could be the problem?

Ok, here is the actual code:

```
def test_add():
'''Testfunction for add'''
assert add(1)==li+[1]
assert add(2)==li+[1, 2]
assert add(3)==li+[1, 2, 3]


def add(n):
'''Adds a new element to the list of scores.
    n is an integer number between 1 and 100.
    Returns the new list'''
global li
li.append(n)
return li
```

it is part of a much longer program, so i can't post it all. when i run the testfunction, it gives me a nameerror, saying that 'add' is not defined.

Comment: That code will give an AssertionError, not a NameError.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Yeah, no names, so no NameError.  Except for the function `add()` -- are you sure that's not in a separate file or scope and therefore not reachable from inside `test_add()`?

Comment: As @Daniel Roseman pointed out, your code (including actual) produces `AssertionError`s not `NameErrors` -- which is correct because the list `add()` returns already has the number added to it, so it's not going to be the same as appending the number to that again.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted will not throw a `NameError`. Whatever you'd doing in your *actual* code is different. You should probably post your *actual, runnable* code (which you have yourself ran as posted and seen the error).